# Cannot set range variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm brand new to VBA and trying to learn variables. I have a simple piece of code that *should* set a variable to a range:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim DataRange As Range
    DataRange = Workbooks("Rooms.csv").Sheets(1).Range("A3", "AK17068")
End Sub
```

When I run I get `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` which.... isn't that what I did with the `Dim` statement? What is this referring to?

I saw [in the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) that in certain cases (I don't fully understand when) I should use `Option Strict On` but when I try to use this I get a syntax error (`Expected: Base or Compare or Explicit or Private`). I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding how this should work (am C++ dev by training)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = Workbooks("Rooms.csv").Sheets(1).Range("A3", "AK17068")
End Sub
```

`Object`Variables are Set with `Set`

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the data range

`Set DataRange = Workbooks("Rooms.csv").Sheets(1).Range("A3", "AK17068")`

Answer (score 1):

Using *With Statement* referring to the workbook & worksheet we are getting the advantage of not repeating workbook & worksheet names if you are planning to set more ranges. See below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim DataRange As Range, DataRange2 As Range

    With Workbooks("Rooms.csv").Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Using *With Statement* referring to the workbook & worksheet
        Set DataRange = .Range("A3", "AK17068")
        Set DataRange2 = .Range("A1") '<- For example purpoces
    End With

End Sub
```